# How to query mysql without a table?

Tags: mysql, boolean

I wonder if I can do a simple boolean check with mysql. I mean can I do something like

```
SELECT WHERE DATE(`2013-03-25 01:22:26`) = CURDATE()
```

to return just true or false?

or a php equivalent of this case would also work, but I want to learn this. Is using mysql for such a goal is unnecessary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove the `WHERE` clause and use single quote around date.

```
SELECT DATE('2013-03-25 01:22:26') = CURDATE()
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/9509)